# Website for Checking Presentation

Tags: forum, presentation

I have many presentations to do for university and were asking myself if there is a website, like a forum, were you can upload your finished presentation and the community can check it and give you some tips for improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is [this](http://www.slideshare.net/) what you're looking for?

Comment: That looks very good, thank you! But what about copyright? Can somebody download my presentation and claim this is his? Or if I upload a presentation, then my tutor finds it on Slideshare, could he think, I just copied it from there?

Comment: http://www.slideshare.net/about you can file copyright complaints if anyone takes your presentation.  And you can put your info like name or whatever detail on the presentation so if you give the link to your professor he know's it's yours.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Google Docs](http://docs.google.com/), which could let you share the presentation to other people and modify it together.

Comment: No, I mean something like a community, where everybody can give feedback. Not just chosen people.